# Is it possible to upload 2 applications into the same heroku plan?

Tags: heroku, server

I am currently paying for a hobby heroku plan and I have already deployed an application, is it possible to have another application (different code and database) running in the same server as mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run as many Heroku apps as you want in your account. However, you need to configure each app to use either free or paid dynos, add-ons etc. independently.

So if you have a second app with different code and DB, you need to provision it separately with either free or paid plans. It will have its own URL, and will incur its own charges.